# Parameter works in ActionResult, but doesn't exist in RouteData in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple ActionResult in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int productId)
{
    return View();
}
```

If I breakpoint it, I can confirm the productId is being passed through and is not null. However, if I examine my RouteData:

```
(int)RouteData.Values["productId"]
```

There's nothing there. There's a key for controller and a key for the action, but nothing for the parameter? What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you declare the `productId` as token somewhere in your routes?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{productId}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", productId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you haven't don't expect to find it in the `RouteData` collection. This collection contains only tokens that were declared in your routes.

The default route uses `id` (the one generated by Visual Studio wizard), so you could rename your action parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

which would totally make sense in a `ProductsController` for example. And now you will find it in `RouteData.Values["id"]`.